# I see an answer with absolutely no user information - should I flag it?

Tags: support

Over on Stack Overflow there's an answer to a question - [Best Practices for Comments on Code Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754905/best-practices-for-comments-on-code-commit/1352189#1352189) - with absolutely no user information.

In the past I've seen answers by users who have no profile (name but no link or photo), but this is the first time I've ever seen an answer with no name.

Should I flag this in any way for clean-up, or simply ignore it?

(Realistically, the user is asking a follow-up question to an answer, but assuming his rep was lower than the threshold, couldn't post a comment to an answer.)

Comment: Thanks to whomever cleaned that answer up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you don't have to. That account is deleted for some reasons.

Comment: I guess normally I still see at least a user name (just not linked), which is why I assumed there was a clean-up issue. You sneaked in right before Bill, so accepted is your's. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That's flaggable for being a follow-up question posted as an answer, but the lack of user information isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's frequent to see answer without profile.

- Can be anonymous
- Can be from a user on a different StackExchange site and question got migrated to one site where the user do not have the account.

So no you do not have to flag this.

On the other hand, if the answer is not an answer but a follow-up to other answer with new question inside it, the problem is not the same. And then it should be flaged as "Not a real answer"

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of anonymous and moved questions, but no user name really threw me.